# Extract part of string in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge Dataframe like below

```py
    Event_ID Name    CompanyAd                                                                                      ticket  Revenue Expences    
0   G-00001  ABC     a097ABSD00E1|ABS_DEw|51Job, Inc.Cayman_Islands NMS|01922453|909234                                 671     6720    150     
1   G-00002  CSA     a097A34D10E1|ABS_DEw|724 Solution's Inc. Canada NMS|90922453|209234                                5       56      18      
2   G-00003  CSA     a097ABSD20E1|ABS_DEw|A B SKF_Sweden OTC+|70922453|509234                                           5       78      38      
3   G-00004  VSX     a097ABSD00E1|ABS_DEw|A/S Steamship Company$ Torm Denmark"s NMS OTC+|2092286453|09234               23      34      23      
4   G-00005  ABC     a09712SD00E1|ABS_DEw|ABB Ltd. Switzerland OTC+|09262453|092394                                     4       89      150     
5   G-00006  ABC     a097ABS680E1|ABS_DEw|Aber Diamond Ltd. Canada CAP MKT|0922453|092234                               60      73      55      
6   G-00007  CSA     a097ABSD23E1||Abitibi Consolidated Inc. Canada OTC +|092245653|0925634                             60      345     110     
7   G-00008  ABC     a09734SD00E1|ABS_DEw|ABN Amro Bank's N.V. Netherlands AMEX - Preferred OTC+|560922453|09234        89      890     150     
8   G-00009  VSX     a397ABSD00E1|ABS_DEw|ABN Amro Holding N.V. Netherlands NYSE|092242353|09234                        0       0       0       
9   G-00010  CSA     a097AB5560E1|ABS_DEw|Acambis plc United Kingdom OTC +|0922453|0926734                              6       45      16      
10  G-00011  VSX     a097A12D00E1|ABS_DEw|Ace Aviation Holdings'aed Inc. Canada OTC|02922453|09234                      3       39      23      
11  G-00012  ABC     a097ABSD00E1||Acetex Corp. Canada OTC - Debt+|097722453|092234                                     2       34      150     
12  G-00013  VSX     a097ABS560E1|ABS_DEw|Acrex Ventures, Ltd. Canada OTC+|0922453|0967234                              4       89      48      
13  G-00014  VSX     a097AqwD00E1|ABS_DEw|ACS-Tech 80 Ltd. Israel CAP MKT|09242453|0956234                              32      127     35      
14  G-00015  ABC     a097ABS230E1|ABS_DEw|Actions Semiconductor Co. Ltd. Cayman Islands NMS|092234453|0923674           3       84      55      
15  G-00016  ABC     a097ABS900E1||Adastra Minerals Inc. Canada OTC*|092246753|0928934                                  1       100     150     
16  G-00017  CSA     a097dfrD00E1|ABS_DEw|ADB Systems International Inc. Canada OTC|092234453|09234                     23      525     90
```

I want to extract "CompanyAd" from a long string and can be used second "|" and 3rd "|" as identifiers. So it should be exactly what is in the middle of the second "|" and 3rd "|".

```py
    Event_ID Name    CompanyAd                                                  ticket  Revenue Expences
0   G-00001  ABC     51Job, Inc.Cayman_Islands NMS                              671     6720    150     
1   G-00002  CSA     724 Solution's Inc. Canada NMS                             5       56      18      
2   G-00003  CSA     A B SKF_Sweden OTC+                                        5       78      38      
3   G-00004  VSX     A/S Steamship Company$ Torm Denmark"s NMS OTC+             23      34      23      
4   G-00005  ABC     ABB Ltd. Switzerland OTC+                                  4       89      150     
5   G-00006  ABC     Aber Diamond Ltd. Canada CAP MKT                           60      73      55      
6   G-00007  CSA     Abitibi Consolidated Inc. Canada OTC +                     60      345     110     
7   G-00008  ABC     ABN Amro Bank's N.V. Netherlands AMEX - Preferred OTC+     89      890     150     
8   G-00009  VSX     ABN Amro Holding N.V. Netherlands NYSE                     0       0       0       
9   G-00010  CSA     Acambis plc United Kingdom OTC +                           6       45      16      
10  G-00011  VSX     Ace Aviation Holdings'aed Inc. Canada OTC                  3       39      23      
11  G-00012  ABC     Acetex Corp. Canada OTC - Debt+                            2       34      150     
12  G-00013  VSX     ABS_DEw|Acrex Ventures, Ltd. Canada OTC+                   4       89      48      
13  G-00014  VSX     ABS_DEw|ACS-Tech 80 Ltd. Israel CAP MKT                    32      127     35      
14  G-00015  ABC     ABS_DEw|Actions Semiconductor Co. Ltd. Cayman Islands NMS  3       84      55      
15  G-00016  ABC     Adastra Minerals Inc. Canada OTC*|092246753|0928934        1       100     150     
16  G-00017  CSA     ADB Systems International Inc. Canada OTC                  23      525     90
```

I was trying to use regex pattern extraction but didn't succeed. Any help would be appreciate.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What pattern did you try and how exactly did it fail?

Comment: Please quote your data properly so that I can import it, or replace spaces with underscores, or add delimiters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could string split instead of regex? Then list comprehension like:

```
df["CompanyAd"] = [x.split("|")[2] for x in df["CompanyAd"]]
```

Hopefully this works

Answer (score 1):

If it is always at 3rd position, you can do this:

```
df['CompanyAd'] = df['CompanyAd'].str.split('|').str[2]
print(df['CompanyAd'])
```

```
0                         51Job, Inc.Cayman_Islands NMS
1                        724 Solution's Inc. Canada NMS
2                                   A B SKF_Sweden OTC+
3        A/S Steamship Company$ Torm Denmark"s NMS OTC+
4                             ABB Ltd. Switzerland OTC+
5                      Aber Diamond Ltd. Canada CAP MKT
6                Abitibi Consolidated Inc. Canada OTC +
7     ABN Amro Bank's N.V. Netherlands AMEX - Prefer...
8                ABN Amro Holding N.V. Netherlands NYSE
9                      Acambis plc United Kingdom OTC +
10            Ace Aviation Holdings'aed Inc. Canada OTC
11                      Acetex Corp. Canada OTC - Debt+
12                     Acrex Ventures, Ltd. Canada OTC+
13                      ACS-Tech 80 Ltd. Israel CAP MKT
14    Actions Semiconductor Co. Ltd. Cayman Islands NMS
15                    Adastra Minerals Inc. Canada OTC*
16            ADB Systems International Inc. Canada OTC
Name: CompanyAd, dtype: object
```